# MySQL - WHERE / HAVING count

Tags: php, mysql

I searched lots of similar topics about this but can't find the answer to this specific probem.

So I have a table with categories and I have another table with products, so what I want is select all the categories that contain at least 1 product, seems very easy but the following code dont give me what I expect.

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
INNER JOIN products on (categories.id = products.cat_id)
HAVING count(products.cat_id) > 0
```

All help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You need `GROUP BY`. But you don't need the `HAVING` clause at all, since `INNER JOIN` won't return any rows if there's nothing matching in the `products` table.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY products.cat_id` before your `HAVING` clause.

Comment: An inner-join already excludes rows where there is not a matching categories.id on either side ...

Comment: you're doing an inner join. the having is redundant, as inner joins require there be matching records on BOTH sides of the join. Maybe you just want a `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM categories ...`

Comment: Come on, a little research never hurt anyone

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, it was so easy. I had used INNER JOIN in the past on other projects and also GROUP BY, but never combined the both.

@Strawberry Don't be so mean to people, I did research, I'm sorry if I'm not as good as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually get what you want with just a join because any categories without products will not match.

You should also add a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to remove the duplicate category records from the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.* 
  FROM categories c
  JOIN products p
    ON c.id = p.cat_id
```

OR:

```
  SELECT c.* 
    FROM categories c
    JOIN products p
      ON c.id = p.cat_id 
GROUP BY c.id
```

If you want something fancy like categories that have 2 or more products then you can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
  SELECT c.* 
    FROM categories c
    JOIN products p
      ON c.id = p.cat_id 
GROUP BY c.id
  HAVING count(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this select in this select all categories that have at least one product

```
select categories.* from categories 
left join products on (categories.id = products.cat_id) 
where products.cat_id IS NOT NULL
group by categories.id
```

In this case you're not using "HAVING" but will have the same result

Comment: Why oh why would you want to hack a LEFT JOIN to do an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Lol, I know what a LEFT JOIN does.. but you are effectively doing an INNER JOIN, why not use the right tool for the job? Also `<>` is not `NULL` safe, so you would never get any results. Use `IS NOT NULL` if you insist.